# pull data or html from a live site using ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm using a local server currently (example: localhost:99999/main ) and I am trying to see if I can pull data or html from a live site ( example: https://developers.google.com/ ). So far I've used:

```
function pullWeb(){
    var url = "https://developers.google.com/",
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: url,
        dataType: 'jsonp', // I've also used html
        success: function (data) {
            console.log('hit it');
        },
        error: function (exception) { alert('Exeption:' + exception); }
    });
}
```

Are there restrictions to pulling in live site data? Currently it goes through the call and gives me an error but its just { object; object }

Comment: Yes there are restrictions called CORS (Cross origin resource sharing). Rare that you can access html using ajax on another site. You would need to use a proxy

Comment: I did see that, but I have a fellow developer with basically the same code and he got it to work ( except he doesn't know how ) so maybe he did something he didn't know he did, which is why i'm asking

Comment: Probably because the resource he was pointing at was configured to do what he was requesting. There is no *"one size fits all"*. Also don't use `alert()` for debugging...log that object to console

Comment: ok thanks for the input

Comment: `alert('Exeption:' + exception);` will give you [object Object] because it's an object and can't natively be displayed as a string. `alert('Exception:' + JSON.stringify(exception));` will probably show you better. Or you can check your browser's network tab in the developer tools and examine the ajax request.

Comment: ok ill try that thanks